# The output file of constraint {igraph} in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am using igraph package in R to compute Burt's constraint for each vertex (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/constraint).

The output I get as a result of running the command `constraint(g, weights=NULL)` is the following:

```
       vertex1    vertex2    vertex3    vertex4    vertex5    vertex6    vertex7
    1.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.29986736
       vertex8    vertex9   vertex10   vertex11   vertex12   vertex13   vertex14
    1.00000000 1.00000000 0.25000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.50000000 1.00000000
       ...
    vertex1000
    0.25000000
```

My question is how do I export this into a xlsx (or csv, txt) file with the following structure:

```
vertex1 1.00000000
vertex2 0.50000000
vertex3 0.50000000
...
vertex1000 0.25000000
```

Would be grateful for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your input MrFlick. I found the answer. It is a little bit more complicated than just using `data.frame`. I post the code to transform Burt's contraint outcome from the `igraph` package in R into the vertex-constraint form below:

```
library("igraph")
library("reshape2")
edge_list=read.delim("your_valued_edgelist.txt")
g=graph.data.frame(edge_list, directed=FALSE, vertices=NULL)
x<-capture.output(melt(constraint(g, weights=NULL)))
x$id <- rownames(x)
x[1] <- NULL
y<-data.frame(vertex_id=substr(x,1,6), constraint_score=as.numeric(substr(x,8,13)))
write.table(y, file = "your_outcome.txt", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, sep="\t")
```

In my case I had to `substring` my vertex_id by first six characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the results to a variable `x`, try

```
write.csv( data.frame(vertex=names(x), value=x), "out.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: I save results to `x` by:
`x<-capture.output(constraint(g, weights=NULL))`

But then when I use `write.csv` command I get the following error message:
`Error in data.frame(vertex = names(x), value = x) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 982`

In fact, I have more than 1000 vertices. The number of rows with vertices and "constraint" values below is 982 apparently: 9 vertices per row and 9 "constraint" values below.